# sudo sshuttle without password

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I found an article http://superuser.com/questions/611511/how-to-launch-sshuttle-without-superuser-pwd-prompt, but when I try `ps auxwww |grep sud`, I get different output:

```
root      2846  0.0  0.1  79104  4328 pts/0    S+   08:27   0:00 sudo -p [local sudo] Password:  PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages -- /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/sshuttle --method auto --firewall
```

So I tried to replace

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/share/sshuttle/main.py /usr/bin/python -v --firewall 12300 0
```

with my case:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages -- /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/sshuttle --method auto --firewall
```

When I finished editing,visudo says my grammar is wrong; what's my mistake and how to get the things done?

Comment: It would be easier to see what is wrong if you showed the entire line you're trying to put into your sudo configuration and that `visudo` is unhappy about. My guess would be that you should not include the setting of PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I add this two lines to the end of my sudo configuration


`Cmnd_Alias SSHUTTLE = /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/sshuttle --method auto --firewall`  `iucmr ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: SSHUTTLE`

Comment: Then error when I run sshuttle   

`iucmr@ricn:~$ sshuttle -r root@111.111.111.111 0/0 --dns -x 111.111.111.111 --python '/usr/bin/python3.6'   'sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: PYTHONPATH
fatal: ['sudo', '-p', '[local sudo] Password: ', 'PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '--', '/usr/bin/python3', '/usr/bin/sshuttle', '--method', 'auto', '--firewall'] returned 1`

Comment: Then error when I run sshuttle
`iucmr@ricn:~$ sshuttle -r root@111.111.111.111 0/0 --dns -x 111.111.111.111 --python '/usr/bin/python3.6'`

Comment: `sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: PYTHONPATH
fatal: ['sudo', '-p', '[local sudo] Password: ', 'PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '--', '/usr/bin/python3', '/usr/bin/sshuttle', '--method', 'auto', '--firewall'] returned 1`

Answer (score 1):

Thats it...

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
Defaults        env_keep += PYTHONPATH

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias SSHUTTLE =  /usr/bin/python3 , /usr/bin/sshuttle --method auto --firewall

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
your_username    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SSHUTTLE

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Isn't `#includedir /etc/sudoers.dde here` a syntax error? What's the intention of that line?

Comment: Actually, [it's not a comment](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html); `#includedir` is a valid directive "used to create a sudoers.d directory that the system package manager can drop sudoers rules into as part of package installation"

Comment: Since you've addressed the sshuttle question with the previous lines, I would suggest removing the last 3 lines altogether. (and perhaps even the last 5 lines)

Comment: Isn't #includedir /etc/sudoers.dde here a syntax error? YES. Editing.

Comment: I feel like this post would be better if it focused on answering the question by removing the `%sudo` section onwards. It doesn't even need the `root` line.